# CiviContribute/CiviCRM overrides content entered into a custom field each time a donation is made

Tags: civicontribute, custom-fields, drupal-8, drupal-7

Hopefully I can explain this so it makes sense. :)

We have customers that have donation pages (and events) that they use custom fields with, but when someone completes the custom field once, it does show in the contact's profile. If the same person comes back and makes another contribution, but chooses a different option for the custom field, it overrides what they entered previously.

We work with a lot of nonprofits, so they have people making multiple donations at different times throughout the year (and sometimes monthly), but they need to have a record of each designation the donor selects every time they make a donation.

Is there a way to prevent the information in the custom field from being overridden each time someone donates with a different designation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Hopefully it makes sense.

Let me know if you need any further information. :)

Thank You!

Nicole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your custom fields are on the contact record. If you create custom fields on the contribution instead then you avoid the problem.

Comment: oh my god. duh. thank you so much! :)

Comment: one more question... hopefully this is ok... :) would it be the same thing for CiviEvents with custom profile fields? thank you!

Comment: Yes ... but if you are wanting to record custom info about someone's participation in the event, put the custom field on the Participant record, not the Event.  If you want a longer answer ask it as a new question :-)

Comment: thank you so much!